# How can I delete tkinter entry boxes when the spinbox reduces in number?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to write code for a simple gpa calculator. I am trying to add an option of how many courses a person is taking, and produce an equal amount of entry boxes. But after adding an entry box, I am unable to delete it when the number reduces. Code below

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
list1 = []
def add_entry():
    global list1
    for i in range(0,int(spin1.get())):
        if int(spin1.get()) >= int(i)+1:
            entry1= Entry(root)
            entry1.grid(row=int(i)+1, column=0)


spin1 = Spinbox(root, from_=0, to=10, width=5, command=add_entry)
spin1.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2)
```

I understand that it is a simple concept but I am trying to learn it on my own and am finding it had. Thank you[This is the problem i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DratX.png)

Comment: Save the entries to a list so that you can later refer to them by index. You can then call `.destroy()` on the ones yo don't want.

Comment: You have declared `list1`, but never use it to save the entries.  You need to compare the value of the spinbox with the size of `list1`.  If the value of the spinbox is greater than the size of `list1`, create new entries and append them to `list1`.  If the value of the spinbox is less than the size of `list1`, destroy the extra entries and truncate `list1`.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It worked, thanks